# Precise algorithm for finding higher order derivatives

Tags: algorithms, mathematical-programming, numerical-algorithms, mathematical-analysis, numerical-analysis

I'm trying to make an algorithm that finds the first 10 or so terms of a function's Taylor series, which requires finding the nth derivative of the function for the nth term. It's easy to implement derivatives by following the definition of the derivative:
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
implemented here in Python:

```
dx = 0.001
def derivative(f, x):
    return (f(x + dx) - f(x)) / dx
```

The value seems to be even closer to the actual value of the derivative if we define it like this:

```
dx = 0.001
def derivative(f, x):
    return (f(x + dx) - f(x - dx)) / (2 * dx)
```

which just returns the average of `(f(x + dx) - f(x)) / dx` and `(f(x) - f(x - dx)) / dx`.

---

For higher order derivatives, I implemented a simple recursive function:

```
dx = 0.001
def nthDerivative(f, n, x):
    if n == 0:
        return f(x)
    return (derivative(f, n - 1, x + dx) - derivative(f, n - 1, x - dx)) / (2 * dx)
```

I tested the higher order derivatives of $f$ at $1$, where $f(x)=x^9$, and as can be proved by induction,
$$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^k)=\dfrac{k!}{(k - n)!}x^{k-n}$$

Therefore, the nth derivative of $f$ at $1$ is $\dfrac{9!}{(9 - n)!}$.
Here are the values returned by the function for n ranging from 0 to 9:

```
n             Value  Intended value
-----------------------------------
0             1.000               1
1             9.000               9
2            72.001              72
3           504.008             504
4          3024.040            3024
5         15120.252           15120
6         60437.602           60480
7         82298.612          181440
8      32278187.177          362880
9   95496943657.736          362880
```

As you can see, the values are waaaay off for $n$ greater than $5$.

---

What can I do to get closer to the actual values? And is there an algorithm for this that doesn't have $O(2^n)$ performance like mine?

Comment: Are you asking about "numerically defined" functions, or those described by differentiable "component" functions.  I ask because if the latter, you can determine higher derivative fairly trivially, without numerical errors caused by small time steps.  This technique is inexplicably (to me) relatively unknown in the numerical analysis world.  See here for an example: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fb1d/3e93f5f393d1487db900e8b3c9c30ae0d963.pdf

Comment: Non-direct PDF link https://www.aimsciences.org/article/doi/10.3934/proc.2013.2013.587 from author's home page:  https://www.neidinger.net/publicat.html

Comment: I have reproduced correct results in the Python version of my software. https://github.com/m4r35n357/ODE-Playground/tree/python.  This is from an ipython session (I have used vertical bars in place of carriage returns):
Context.places = 6 |
a = Series.get(10, 1.0).var |
print(~(a * a * a * a * a * a * a * a * a)) |
+1.000000e+00 +9.000000e+00 +7.200000e+01 +5.040000e+02 +3.024000e+03 +1.512000e+04 +6.048000e+04 +1.814400e+05 +3.628800e+05 +3.628800e+05

Comment: BTW, print(~(a**9)) also works if you can bear the domain restriction a>0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should understand is why central differencing gives you a more precise solution.

Consider the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $x$:

$$f(x + h) = f(x) + h f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x) + \frac{1}{3!} h^3 f'''(x) \cdots$$

Then:

$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h f''(x) +  \frac{1}{3!} h^2 f'''(x)\cdots$$

That is:

$$f'(x) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} + O(h)$$

However:

$$f(x - h) = f(x) - h f'(x) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x) - \frac{1}{3!} h^3 f'''(x) \cdots$$

Therefore:

$$f(x + h) - f(x-h) = 2 h f'(x) + \frac{2}{3!} h^3 f'''(x) \cdots$$

And so:

$$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x-h)}{2h} = f'(x) + O(h^2)$$

With central differencing, the even terms of the Taylor series cancel, and you get a second-order approximation instead of a first-order approximation.

(Note that in real-world problems, central differencing is not always possible for many reasons. In fluid dynamics, for example, you do not want to do a central differencing approximation across a [shock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_(fluid_dynamics)), so you generally only approximate derivatives using values that are ["upwind"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upwind_scheme) of the point of interest. I digress.)

You can think of approximating high-order derivatives as solving for the coefficients of the Taylor expansion. To find the first derivative, you solve for the first two coefficients. Since there are two unknowns, you need two equations. To calculate the second derivative as well, you need a third equation at least.

This doesn't seem like a game that you can win. If you obtain more points by using smaller values of $h$, then numerical evaluation becomes more unstable; if $f(x)$ and $f(x+h)$ are close in value, then $f(x+h) - f(x)$ can easily suffer from [catastrophic cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation). If you use larger values of $h$, then the $O(h)$ or $O(h^2)$ error term is larger. For a given $h$, there are only two points at distance $h$ from $x$ on the real line.

However, there are as many points (at a distance $h$ from $x$) as you want in the complex plane. So if $f$ is holomorphic, and $f(x) = x^9$ is holomorphic, you can obtain some extremely high-precision derivative estimates by picking points on a circle around $x$.

Back to central differencing for a moment, this works by eliminating the even terms of the Taylor approximation. You may wonder if it's possible to extend this to eliminate higher-order terms.

Suppose that $A_k(h)$ is a $k$th-order approximation to some desired value $L$. That is, there are some constants $c_i$ such that:

$$A_k(h) = L + c_k h^k + c_{k+1} h^{k+1} + c_{k+2} h^{k+2} + \cdots$$

Let's look at what happens if you halved $h$:

$$A_k(\frac{h}{2}) = L + \frac{1}{2^k} c_k h^k + \frac{1}{2^{k+1}} c_{k+1} h^{k+1} + \frac{1}{2^{k+2}} c_{k+2} h^{k+2} + \cdots$$

Then:

$$2^k A_k(\frac{h}{2}) - A(h) = \left(2^k - 1\right) L + O(h^{k+1})$$

And so this:

$$A_{k+1}(h) = \frac{2^k A_k(\frac{h}{2}) - A_k(h)}{2^k - 1}$$

is a $k+1$th-order approximation. And, of course, you can iterate to find higher order approximations.

Even though this technique uses smaller and smaller step sizes, you can control the numeric issues by using a factor $t$ other than 2:

$$R(h,t) = \frac{t^k A(\frac{h}{t}) - A(h)}{t^k - 1}$$

This is known as [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation), and it turns out to be extremely useful in [estimating derivatives](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2590055219300332).

Comment: I would be interested in your opinion of my comment to the OP.  I have implemented and used the method myself and it really is an eye-opener!  It is trivial to calculate derivatives up to the order of _hundreds_ effficiently, without losing precision caused by finite differences.  Here is an example of someone taking it to ridiculous degree on a supercomputer! https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.4222  I don't have the mathematical "chops" to give a good answer, but hopefully this comment will be useful.

Comment: @m4r35n357 You're answering a different question. The Clean Numerical Simulation method uses symbolic derivatives, where the task here is to estimate them.

Comment: Not so, it is definitely numerical, using Cauchy products of Taylor series at its core (see for example the Neidinger paper I referred to in the OP).  Symbolic derivatives are subject (as I understand it) to Faà di Bruno's formula.  There is _no way_ that you can do that calculation with 3500 order, or even print the results!  In any case "clean numerical simulation" is a principle (comparing your results with those from a "better" integrator) rather than a specific method.  Thanks for replying though, I've been itching to talk about this for a long time!

Comment: Running out of space, so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula   BTW please bear in mind that I am not a mathematician, just a "happy amateur" who likes to experiment with interesting numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you use memoization, your algorithm will have $O(n^2)$ running time, instead of $O(2^n)$ running time.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Higher_derivatives.

You might check the value of $dx$ you are using (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation#Step_size); and check whether you are experiencing numerical roundoff/precision issues.

One other possible approach is to evaluate the function at 10-20 randomly chosen points near $x$, and then fit a 10th order polynomial to those points using least-squares polynomial regression.